# NodeJS (ES6): SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

```
let {name, description} = req.body;
```

NodeJS v5.2.0.
Tried using flags - node bin/www --es_staging --harmony_destructuring. Throws an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token {...
Should I compile source using Babel, or is there any other way to use ES6 natively in NodeJS?

Comment: I think this isn't supported yet on Node 5.0. Babel does seem to support that according to [this](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-destructuring,_declarations)

Comment: I recommend to read the official documentation, which would have answered your question: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Destructuring assigments are not supported by default in Node 5.2.0, but it will work if you enable it with `node --harmony_destructuring`.

However `let` is only supported in strict mode for now.
This is a V8 issue, and Node version 5.0.0, which will include V8 version 4.6 will also support `let` in sloppy mode.

Using `let` in sloppy mode at the moment, will throw the exact same error you're getting, so :

```
"use strict"

let {name, description} = {name: "some name", description : "some description"};
```

works fine in Node 5.2.0, note that the object, in your case `req.body`, must have the same keys as the variable names, otherwise they'll be `undefined`.