# Unexpected token { when trying gulp with JS ES6

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-babel

Am I using wrong version of some package or can you post me a link to the detailed tutorial or codepen where this syntax construction do not give me an error?

I am getting this error:

```
$ gulp
D:\GIT\project02\gulpfile.js:20
const { COMPATIBILITY, PORT, UNCSS_OPTIONS, PATHS } = loadConfig();
      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at execute (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0-alpha.2\index.js:36:18)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\index.js:172:63)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm\node_modules\gulp-cli\node_modules\liftoff\index.js:198:16)
```

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373026/nodejs-es6-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), but `'use strict';` was in my gulpfile, and changing const to let didn't worked for me.

My globally installed packages:

```
$ npm -g ls --depth=0
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Application Data\npm
├── babel-cli@6.14.0
├── babel-core@6.14.0
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.14.0
├── bower@1.7.9
├── gulp-babel@6.1.2
└── gulp-cli@1.2.2 (git://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-cli.git#9b053ed9b7a63a10777c33b86b04ed38d7f5b840)
```

My Node is `v4.0.0` and gulp that I am using in project:

```
$ gulp -v
[14:15:06] CLI version 1.2.2
[14:15:06] Local version 4.0.0-alpha.2
```

Comment: Duplicate Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745118/browserify-babel-6-gulp-unexpected-token-on-spread-operator

Comment: @user2249160 not entirely a duplicate: the error here is because `Gulpfile.js` itself contains the destructuring statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Konstantin already said, not all ES6 features are available in your Gulpfile, because node has to process those files. But there is an easy way to do this by using the `babel-require` hook.

Create a Gulpfile like this:

```
'use strict';

// Compile task to ES5 on the fly!
require('babel-register');

// Require all tasks!
require('require-dir')('./tasks', { recurse: true });
```

and put your tasks inside the `tasks` directory. Then create a `.babelrc` file to load a preset, e.g.

```
{
    "presets": ["node5"]
}
```

when you're using node *v5.x*. Now you can use ES6 features! :)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. It is very instructive! I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

[Destructing](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-destructuring-in-depth#destructuring) is ES6 feature and it's officially supported starting from Node v6. So you should replace:

```
const { COMPATIBILITY, PORT, UNCSS_OPTIONS, PATHS } = loadConfig();
```

With:

```
const config =  loadConfig(),
      COMPATIBILITY = config.COMPATIBILITY,
      PORT = config.PORT,
      UNCSS_OPTIONS = config.UNCSS_OPTIONS,
      PATHS = config.PATHS
```

Or update your Node version.